# flask app not rendering html tags properly

Tags: python, flask, markup

I have a sentence

```
sentence =  <p> Reading, watching or <span class="matching">listening</span> to the media isn’t <span class="matching">matching</span><span class="matching">much</span> help either. </p>
```

to make it render properly at front-end here is what I have done

```
from flask import Markup
sentence = Markup(sentence)
```

But the output is only rendered properly for one markup (not necessarily first one) and others are not rendered.

```
            <p> Reading, watching or <span class="matching">listening</span> to the media isn’t &lt;span class=&#34;matching&#34;&gt;much&lt;/span&gt; help either. </p>
```

What am I doing it wrong here?

Comment: In django we would do something like this: {{ variable_name|safe }}

Comment: I got following error when I tried your example in terminal: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)" Didn't you get such error? Here is the SO link to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-string

Comment: Thanks @rajpy the link you posted has an function which removes all the non ascii characters and it makes it easier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is the

> isn’t

that "’" is not valid ASCII, because of which it doesn't come in the valid range of characters of HTML Markup , thus it escapes it (though it should throw an error)

Hope that solves the issue.

This works for me

```
from flask import Markup
sentence =  '<p> Reading, watching or <span class="matching">listening</span> to the media isn\'t <span class="matching">matching</span><span class="matching">much</span> help either. </p>'
Markup(sentence)
```

returns

```
Markup(u'<p> Reading, watching or <span class="matching">listening</span> to the media isn\'t <span class="matching">matching</span><span class="matching">much</span> help either. </p>')
```

hope that is what is the required output

Comment: ok. You see the culprit and you have manually edited and added escape to make it valid HTML Markup. But I have gazillions of sentences. How do you first change those sentence to valid HTML Markup?

Comment: well, you can write a script to either remove all characters out of range .. or replace them with a valid one .. :D