# I want to call my bingo.sh file through python in mac how to do that?

Tags: python, macos, shell

os.system('sh ~/scripts/bingo.sh')
 this gives an error of  Non ascii characters.

Comment: It woks for me.Have you tried this
`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`

Comment: yes i tried this it's giving me sytax error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sh","/full/path/bingo.sh"])
```

Comment: its giving me an error of invalid syntax after the square brackets of invalid syntax  subprocess.call(["sh","/full/path/bingo.sh"])

Comment: @SaddamHk Hmm I ran it with no problem. Did you change /full/path/bingo.sh to the actually location on your file system?

Comment: ye i have given it the full path as follows subprocess.call(["sh","/Users/Saddam.Khattak/trytry/bingo.sh"])

Comment: it working now Thank you very much.I was using a text editor due to which it was giving the syntax error but when i used the same command with Python idle  its working fine now

Comment: @SaddamHk Great News! If this is a solution that worked for you, can you please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

"Python 2 uses ascii as the default encoding for source files, which means you must specify another encoding at the top of the file to use non-ascii unicode characters in literals. Python 3 uses utf-8 as the default encoding for source files, so this is less of an issue"

I was able to find this by googling "Python error 'Non ascii characters'"
From my understanding this is a good answer

[How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342000/7408023)

hope this helps
(I am new to coding and was looking into this to help my own understanding of how to avoid this problem for myself. Take what I have to say with a grain of salt.)