# python-scrapinghub, ascii / utf8?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.4, scrapinghub

Python 3.4.2

i'm  using the Client interface for Scrapinghub API, which can be found here:

https://github.com/scrapinghub/python-scrapinghub

I Scrape a site and want get and print the items with

```
for item in job.items():
  print(item)
```

In a python interpreter this works fine but when i export my code in a script (f.e. 'test.py' and run it with 'python3 test.py' an error occures, which says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
print(insert_statement)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdf' in position 247: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The text of line 24 is sth like this : [ ... ] Tobias Weiß [...]

I already run 'dpkg-reconfigure locales' and set it to 'de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8' but it does not seems to be the problem.

Do i have to convert the item dict to utf8 for every result or is there another solution i don't see.

```
from scrapinghub import Connection

conn = Connection('1234567890')
project = conn[123456]



jobs = project.jobs(state='finished')

for job in jobs:
    if "consumed" not in job.info['tags']:
            for item in job.items():
                   print(item)
```

Regards

Comment: try adding this at the beginning of the file: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Which version of python?

Comment: The problem is that Python considers your console interface to be ASCII only. Not sure offhand how to fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-make-the-python-interpreter-correctly-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-stri)

Comment: In the python interpreter the code runs fine but i exported it to a script file 'test.py' and run it with 'python3 test.py' - there the error occures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, which seems to work.

In the shell i had to type:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Also i followed instrcutions from here: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/17/introducing-scrapy-cloud-with-python-3-support/

> Introducing Scrapy Cloud with Python 3 Support

Thanks to all anyways!