# replace non ascii characters in python

Tags: python-3.x, non-ascii-characters

Does anyone know how to replace a non ascii char in python3?
I use as an example but it doesn't work the way I want to, that is to modify the new var as a string.

```
body = "ALYSS - PYRAMID ♅"
newbody = body.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make the python interpreter correctly handle non-ASCII characters in string operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342000/how-to-make-the-python-interpreter-correctly-handle-non-ascii-characters-in-stri)

Comment: Why did you specify the language for your snippet as HTML?  When I click "Run code snippet" it just shows the source code instead of running it.